# Find constant that allows an integral to be finite

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I have a function which is a not-so complicated polynomial, depending on a parameter $c$:

$$f(r,c) = \frac{-2 r^4-4 r^3-6 r^2-6 r-3}{8 r^3}-\frac{c \left(-2 r^2-2 r-1\right)}{4 r^3}$$

What I am looking for is that a functional of this function has a finite integral. Namely, I want the following expression to exist:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} 4 \pi r^2 \left( \exp{(-r)} (1
+f(r,c)\right)^2 \mathrm{d} r$$

If $c=-3/2$, this integralis finite, as I can check with Mathematica:

```
f[r_, c_] := ((-3 - 6 r - 6 r^2 - 4 r^3 - 2 r^4)/(8 r^3) + ((-1 - 2 r - 2 r^2) c)/(4 r^3))
Integrate[(Exp[-r] (1 + f[r, -3/2]))^2*4 \[Pi] r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

The result is $\pi / 16$, as it should be. For other values of $c$ (as far as I know) the integral is not finite. But  I want to check this with *Mathematica*.

The simplest idea I had is to simply ask for the integral as a function of $c$:

```
Integrate[(Exp[-r] (1 + f[r, c]))^2*4 \[Pi] r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

But the output is that the integral does not converge.

How can I find all the values of $c$ where this integral is finite?

Comment: One crude way is to plot the integral as a function of c, there you can see it is converging only for one value of c.

Comment: Maple's answer for the integral is `-signum(c+3/2)*infinity`, so probably your finding `c = -3/2` is the only solution.

Comment: Thank you for that, @Alx , but of course I am still interested in learning if Mathemarica can do it or not.

Comment: Some thought after digging ... We can compute indefinite integral of `r` and take limits. Limit at `r = Infinity` is 0 and formal limit at `r = 0` is undefined. We can make series expansion of that indefinite integral at `r = 0`: `-(3+2 c)^2 \[Pi]/(48 r^3) - (3+2 c)^2 \[Pi]/(16 r^2) + 1/O[r]`. So, formally from this series it follows that with `r = 0` and `c = -3/2` we have value for integral \[Pi]/16.

Comment: SInce the obstruction is a pole of order 1 at the origin, could just force the residue to vanish: `In[188]:= res = 
 Residue[Together[(Exp[-r] (1 + f[r, c]))^2*4 \[Pi] r^2], {r, 0}]

Out[188]= -(1/12) (27 + 24 c + 4 c^2) \[Pi]

In[189]:= Solve[res == 0]

Out[189]= {{c -> -(9/2)}, {c -> -(3/2)}}`

Comment: Where does the open parenthesis at "r^2 ( exp..." close?

Comment: Also " + c(...)/(4r^3)" as you have in the code or " - c(...)/(4r^3)" as you have in the display equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another approach, taking for granted convergence at infinity, is to find values of `c` that annihilate all terms of the series expansion of the integrand at `r == 0` of the form `a*r^-n`:

```
Series[(Exp[-r] (1 + f[r, c]))^2*4 π r^2, {r, 0, -1}]
SolveAlways[Normal@% == 0, r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like this approach, however, it is assumed that the integral does not exist because of the problem at $r=0$. This issue was found by checking the limit of the indefinite integral at this point, which makes sense. However, it can not be excluded that there are no other points of singularity anywhere.

Comment: @Ezze Could you post a better example of what you mean? The only singular points of the integral are $0$ and $\infty$, which is obvious from `f[r,c]`.  (Mathematica will tell you this with `FunctionDomain[f[r, c], r]`, or better `Reduce@Not@FunctionDomain[f[r, c], r]`.)

Comment: You are right, it really can be seen that there are no other singular points.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, extended comment.

This integral is of the form:

```
Integrate[Exp[-2 r] r^n,{n, 0, Infinity}] =
ConditionalExpression[2^(-1 - n) Gamma[1 + n], Re[n] > -1].
```

Now let's look at our integral:

```
Collect[ExpandAll[(Exp[-r] (1 + f[r, c]))^2*4 π r^2], r]
Cases[%, num_ r^n_/;n<0 :> num]
```

[image]

We can solve this for `c`:

```
Solve[# == 0, c] & /@ % // Flatten // Union
```

> {c -> -3/2, c -> -1}

We can check these and make sure that only `c = -3/2` leads to convergent integral of π/16.